# Upload file into a random folder

Tags: c++, google-drive-api, qt4, blackberry-10, google-drive-realtime-api

I want users to upload a file into Google Drive, but not to the root. The Children resource allows only to list folders from the root(which makes sense), but does not put the name of the folders in the JSON response.

I cannot use Parent resource, because the fileID is non-existent and also because i need the users to see the folders(in their respective hierachy) and choose the folder of their choice. Here is what i have tried so far

```
void DriveClass::listFileFolderDrive(const QString& folderID){

QUrl url("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + folderID + "/children");
//qDebug()<<" url for About Drive: "<< url;
QNetworkRequest* request = new QNetworkRequest( url );
request->setHeader( QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json" );
request->setRawHeader( "Authorization", QString( "Bearer %1" ).arg( this->_oAuth2->token() ).toLatin1() );
QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkManager->get(*request);
bool result = connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onlistFileFolderDriveFinished()));
Q_ASSERT(result);
Q_UNUSED(result);
}
```

Where folderID is "root". The response i get is:

```
QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("etag", QVariant(QString, ""dyf6dc5nFpQUIZ2nJvOu2LyLJk8/bD3mjJonFeCjTc8Eu8VRx_DzPtg"") ) ( "items" ,  QVariant(QVariantList, (QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_Ycab1hhT3I0T3ptMDg") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_Ycab1hhT3I0T3ptMDg") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_Ycab1hhT3I0T3ptMDg") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcabXdJd21CeWRHUXM") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcabXdJd21CeWRHUXM") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcabXdJd21CeWRHUXM") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcaM1ZCOXBaZzJSNmc") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcaM1ZCOXBaZzJSNmc") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcaM1ZCOXBaZzJSNmc") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcaSmtNMmRlTld5QkU") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcaSmtNMmRlTld5QkU") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcaSmtNMmRlTld5QkU") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcaY0I0czA4djNLT1U") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcaY0I0czA4djNLT1U") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcaY0I0czA4djNLT1U") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcaTW8zZklsNnFNTDBmQ1dodi1yTFhqX2s4SzNr") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcaTW8zZklsNnFNTDBmQ1dodi1yTFhqX2s4SzNr") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcaTW8zZklsNnFNTDBmQ1dodi1yTFhqX2s4SzNr") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1_eVyijBnZPvFfn4WewtScnlSXRFpXInmop-AUD6Jp5nSV4rnxL4-IpLZ6uoR") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "1_eVyijBnZPvFfn4WewtScnlSXRFpXInmop-AUD6Jp5nSV4rnxL4-IpLZ6uoR") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/1_eVyijBnZPvFfn4WewtScnlSXRFpXInmop-AUD6Jp5nSV4rnxL4-IpLZ6uoR") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_0rcYNi_YcaYmNmZTEwMzYtNjgzZC00MjJkLWFmYWQtZmRlODc4OTEwZTVh") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "0B_0rcYNi_YcaYmNmZTEwMzYtNjgzZC00MjJkLWFmYWQtZmRlODc4OTEwZTVh") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/0B_0rcYNi_YcaYmNmZTEwMzYtNjgzZC00MjJkLWFmYWQtZmRlODc4OTEwZTVh") ) )  ) ,  QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("childLink", QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1CHu3CzJ23I6WS3J8rOIpT5szN8r8mTOxztiWixwXafQ") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(QString, "1CHu3CzJ23I6WS3J8rOIpT5szN8r8mTOxztiWixwXafQ") ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childReference") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AP0rcYNi_YcaUk9PVA/children/1CHu3CzJ23I6WS3J8rOIpT5szN8r8mTOxztiWixwXafQ") ) )  ) )  ) ) ( "kind" ,  QVariant(QString, "drive#childList") ) ( "selfLink" ,  QVariant(QString, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root/children") ) )  )
```

I hope that was clear enough. I parsed it in QVariant so as to use the result in a ListView. From my studying of the google drive docs, one needs a file to have a folderID before inserting can be achieved. And i do not have a folderID for a new file to be uploaded.

Comment: I will need to show us what you have tried and describe any problems you are having with your current solution.   Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you. I have requested a list of the root children folders. The question has been re-edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, was quite wrong... until now. For the record, any upload, whether file or folder, to any  location, whether root or any RANDOM folder, you'd need the folder_id of that particular folder. Use 'root' as id for the root folder. And to upload, you do not need the selfLink, or parentLink. just

```
parents:[{ "id" : "id of the folder, use root for root folder" }]
```

Thank you @pinoyyid.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers...

1. You are using the v2 API. If this is a new app you should probably switch to v3.
2. Your REST call is requesting a list of Children resources. If you look at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children you'll see    that there is no title/name in a children resource.
3. The more common way to achieve what you're looking for is to do a files.list with a query parameter of `folder_id in parents`.

Comment: Thats the thing, but i do not have folder_id ?. If for a new file to be uploaded to any folder, does it mean the folder_id will also be "root"?,  to do a files.list with a query parameter of folder_id in parents.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Oh, What i meant was the parent id, Naturally, you do not need folder_id to upload a file or files.

Comment: parent = folder, so parent_id = folder_id

Comment: True, that works beautifully, when you want to create a folder into another folder, but does not work when you want to upload A file into any given folder.. been trying it for some days now... wont give up though...

Comment: oh and also, maybe i am the one who's wrong, maybe i do not know how to properly represent the parents[] when posting (uploading). I mean the information specifics.